# A simple Python app is behaving erratically for no reason?

Tags: python, python-2.7, random, pygame

I've been going through some Python tutorials using Python 2.7 and Pygame and I decided to challenge myself.  The tutorial showed how to make a ball move (right) across the screen, then pop back to the other (left) side of the screen at a specific speed.  I wanted to make the ball bounce back and forth from left to right, so I wrote this:

```
   bif = "bg.jpg"
    mif = "ball1.png" 

    import pygame, sys
    from pygame import *
    from pygame.locals import * 

    pygame.init() 
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((816,460),0,32) 
    background = pygame.image.load(bif).convert()
    ball = pygame.image.load(mif).convert_alpha()

    x = 0
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()

    while True:

            for event in pygame.event.get():
                    if event.type == QUIT:
                            pygame.quit()
                            sys.exit()

            screen.blit(background, (0,0))
            screen.blit(ball, (x, 160))

            speed = 500
            milli = clock.tick() #A tick is 1 millisecond
            seconds = milli/1000.000000
            dm = seconds * speed

            if x == 0:
                    a = dm
            elif x == 770:
                    a = -dm
            x += a



            pygame.display.update()
```

"bg.jpg" is a jpeg image that is 816 x 460 pixels and "bif.png" is a png image of a ball with a 50 pixel radius.  Instead of moving back and forth at 500 pixels per second, the ball moves at a random speed to the right, then bounces off of the right side of the screen at a random speed to the left, and repeats this a random number of times.  Then the ball keeps going in one direction and doesn't come back.  I can't figure out why it's doing this.  It behaves differently every time I run it.  If anybody can figure out why, I'd be really thankful.

Answer (score 0):

tick(), without arguments returns time which passed since last call. In your use it depends on rendering speed which will always be different that is why you get different speed each time.

Replace from `speed = 500` to the end with:

```
speed = 1

if x == 0 or x == 770:
    speed = -speed
x += speed

pygame.display.update()
clock.tick(60)
```